# How to get current router in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, yii

I am a Zend Framework [version 1] developer, now I am trying to learn the Yii Framework.

How do I get the current router in Yii Framework?

Comment: Are you wanting to pull apart a URL to determine the controller, action, etc? Or are you wanting to put together a URL? Or are you wanting to modify the controller itself?

Comment: There is no "router" in Yii. There's only a route to the current controller and action. Read more [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For an example URL of `http://site.ru/forum/index?var=val`:

- [`Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQueryString()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest/#getQueryString-detail) will return `var=val`,
- [`Yii::app()->getRequest()->getPathInfo()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest/#getPathInfo-detail) will return `forum/index`,
- [`Yii::app()->getRequest()->getBaseUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest/#getBaseUrl-detail) will return `/forum`,
- [`Yii::app()->getRequest()->getUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest/#getUrl-detail) will return `forum/index?var=val`,
- [`Yii::app()->getRequest()->getHostInfo()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest/#getHostInfo-detail) will return `http://site.ru`,
- [`Yii::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest/#getRequestUri-detail) will return `forum/index?var=val`.

Comment: I need to get the current Router, as said by @Michael Härtl.

Answer (score 2):

In case you were after the route, not path related information: in most view files (and the layout) you can use `$this->route` and if you're not in the right context for that to be available view `$this` then you can often use `Yii::app()->controller->route`.

Both return the current matching route from the url manager. Something like:

`site/index`

`site/error`

`user/edit`

Additionally, to just get the current controller in use you can use `$this->id` to return something like `site` or `user`

Answer (score 1):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16000978/1469208) saved me lot of time, but there is a little consideration. I used:

```
Yii::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri(),
```

You should also take the `/` in your result. For example for `http://www.tchaps.ru/ru` you should have `/ru`.